# JavaScript submitting form only if "window.close()" not present

Tags: javascript, django

UPDATE: Working fine in Edge, not working in Chrome.

I have a form with id "myform".

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">{% csrf_token %}
        <label for="target_bla">Bla bla</label>
        <select id="target_bla" name="target_bla">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        
    <div class="buttons">
        {% if condition %}
        <input name="btnSubmit" value="Bla bla" onclick="subAndClose()" />
        {% else %}
        <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Other bla" />
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</form>
```

Then I have this JavaScript part that should submit the form:

```
    function subAndClose() {
        document.forms["myform"].submit();
        window.close()
    }
```

Now the strange thing: When line `window.close()` is omitted, the form submits just fine. When the line is there, the window actually closes, but the form is not submitted at all, without any errors or issues.

**What I have tried already:**

1. I checked all names and IDs, no reserved keywords used
2. I tried submitting with default HTML submit button, it is working properly

UPDATE:

3. I tested with console.log and window.alert and various timeout methods, everything is happening inside the script, just the act of submitting the form is ignored.

Comment: You cant do that, when the window closes any submit is canceled. You should implement this with ajax call then you will be able to submit / close the window.

Comment: If you close the window the form is submitting to before the form submission resolves, then it gets cancelled. If the submission happens in time before that, then the window closes with no feedback to the user about if it was successful or not. Either way, its a poor user experience.

Comment: Browsers tend to cancel any running requests, when you close the window they “belong” to. (Not sure how that comes as a surprise, actually. If I just set you into your car, instruct you to drive to the other side of the country … and then I _crush_ the car in an industrial press immediately after, then I do not actually expect you to arrive at the other side of the country either …)

Comment: A side question: which programmng language contains the syntax `{% ... %}`?

Comment: Nope, this is not a server thing, it works in Edge. I tried timeouts, did not help. With window.close() in script, there is no submit action even starting.

Comment: @Reporter, they are Django tags.

Comment: @PeterVajda then add an appropiate tag to this question

Comment: @Reporter, Django tag was there from the beginning, user Melvyn deleted the tag for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by clearing the browser cache.